# jquery copy select option to another select

Tags: jquery

I want to copy `custom-select` class option list into `custom-multiple-view` class on click event of a tag.

May I know how to copy respective drop down option list to another drop down. I did the following code but doing this all entire HTML page option are get copied, which I don't want.

```js
$('.js-control-edit').on('click', function() {
    $('#select.custom-multiple-view').empty().trigger('refresh');
    $('.js-control-edit').parent().find('select option').trigger('refresh').clone().appendTo('select.custom-multiple-view');   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span class="control-editable"> 
    <select class="custom-select">
        <option value="1">a</option>
        <option value="2">b</option>
    </select>
    <a class="control-edit js-control-edit">...</a>
</span> 
<span class="control-editable"> 
    <select class="custom-select">
        <option value="5">m</option>
        <option value="6">n</option>
    </select>
    <a class="control-edit js-control-edit">...</a>
</span>   
<select class="custom-multiple-view" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, You have an issue with the scope. You may want to use `$(this)` - representing the link you clicked - instead of `$('.js-control-edit')`

Plus, you had a typo on the selector in order to reset your multiple select (no need for `#` as this is an *element* and not an *id* you're looking for)

Check this code (I only changed the jQuery part)

```js
$('.js-control-edit').on('click', function() {
    $('select.custom-multiple-view').empty().trigger('refresh');
    $(this).parent().find('select option').trigger('refresh').clone().appendTo('select.custom-multiple-view');   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span class="control-editable"> 
    <select class="custom-select">
        <option value="1">a</option>
        <option value="2">b</option>
    </select>
    <a class="control-edit js-control-edit">...</a>
</span> 
<span class="control-editable"> 
    <select class="custom-select">
        <option value="5">m</option>
        <option value="6">n</option>
    </select>
    <a class="control-edit js-control-edit">...</a>
</span>   
<select class="custom-multiple-view" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

Comment: $(this) is not working.I want to copy select option list to another select (eg above scenario custom-multiple-view select)on click event of each a tag

Comment: @RupaliPawar just run this code snippet. If you click on each `...` (which are your `a` tags) il will copy the select options attached. Isn't that the behavior you wanted?